# Tridiagonal Lists in Scheme

Tags: matrix, lambda, racket

```
(define (tridiagonal n)
   (build-list n 
               (lambda (x)
                 (build-list n 
                           (lambda (x)
                             (cond
                               [(= x n) 2]
                               [(or (= x (- n 1))
                                    (= x (+ n 1))) 1]
                               [else 0]))))))
```

The above is my attempt at making a tridiagonal patterns of lists.
Restrictions:

- Consumed integer n is greater than 2
- At most 3 non-zero value occour in a list.

Examples:

```
(tridiagonal 3) => (list (list 2 1 0) (list 1 2 1) (list 0 1 2))
(tridiagonal 5) => (list (list 2 1 0 0 0) (list 1 2 1 0 0) (list 0 1 2 1 0) (list 0 0 1 2 1) (list 0 0 0 1 2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually work, because your two lambdas both used `x` as the parameter name, and the inner one shadows the outer one. Here's a fixed version:

```
(define (tridiagonal n)
  (build-list n
              (lambda (x)
                (build-list n
                            (lambda (y)
                              (cond
                                [(= x y) 2]
                                [(or (= x (sub1 y))
                                     (= x (add1 y))) 1]
                                [else 0]))))))
```

This works, but in Racket, it's probably more idiomatic to use `for/list` for creating a list:

```
(define (tridiagonal n)
  (for/list ((i (in-range n)))
    (for/list ((j (in-range n)))
      (max 0 (- 2 (abs (- i j)))))))
```

As you can see, I've taken the liberty of simplifying your `cond` expression too, into a single `(max 0 (- 2 (abs (- i j))))` expression.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the insightful explanation into the logic behind lambda.